# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Determine the type of Authentication Issue

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I presume this is by design (and hence might be a silly question) however is there any way to determine the authentication issue generated when connecting to Dynamics CRM.

I am creating a third party application which connects and I would like to say "Invalid Password" rather than "Authentication Failure". The following is what I have.

```
namespace MyCRM
{
public class MyCRMClass
{
    public static void ConnectToCRM()
    {
        Uri serverURI = new Uri('https://myorganisation.api.crm5.dynamics.com/XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc');
        ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
        clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = 'Username';
        clientCredentials.UserName.Password = 'Password';

        OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serverURI, null, clientCredentials, null);
        serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

        try
        {
            Guid UserId = ((WhoAmIResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Throws Authentication Issue
        }
    }
}
}
```

By calling the WhoAMIRequest I can get an Authentication error however I really want to know what error so I can assist staff with fixing their own issue.

Am I right in suggesting that this is not possible using the CRM webservices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll never be able to get error information like you're requesting from the client side.  You could theoretically turn on trace logging on the server, but that would be a bad idea for a whole slew of reasons.

Generally saying the password is invalid is a security issue because it allows hackers to know that the account is valid and if they could just figure out the password, they're in.

Comment: Thanks Daryl. Thats what I thought

Comment: @JorisVanRegemortel Turning on trace logging for the purpose of debugging isn't bad at all.  It's one of my first steps when debugging an issue.  Turning it on, and leaving it on in production, is going to slow the whole system down and will eventually result in your server's disk being completely full.  All of this danger just for the sole purpose of telling the user that his password is wrong, vs just having an unable to login message, doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: And I"m not even sure it'll tell you in the log if their password is was wrong...